# ffmpeg error while opening encoder for output stream

Tags: ffmpeg, synology

I have 2 versions of ffmpeg installed on my synology DS718+ NAS. It comes with the default and outdated 2.7.1, but I have installed the synocommunity ffmpeg package (4.2.1) as well for improved functionality using tvheadend's mpeg-ts spawn profiles.

Now I have this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -map a -map v -c:v libx264 -vf "yadif=1:-1:1, scale=720:576" -crf 24 -profile:v main -preset veryfast -c:a mp3 -b:a 96k -ac 2 -async 1 -sn -fflags +genpts -metadata service_provider=STRING -metadata service_name=STRING -f mpegts pipe:1
```

If I use **2.7.1** it works (if set c:a aac it doesn't work, since 2.7.1 doesn't have aac), but if I use **4.2.1** it gives me this:

```
spawn:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mp2 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
spawn:   Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (mp2 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
spawn:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
spawn: -async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0.
spawn:     Last message repeated 1 times
spawn: Error initializing output stream 0:2 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
spawn: Conversion failed!
```

Strangely enough if I go for c:a aac in **4.2.1** it crashes at the audio stream.

```
spawn:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
spawn:   Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
spawn:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
spawn: -async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0.
spawn: Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
spawn: Conversion failed!
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Help please.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: This one works (2.7.1)

https://pastebin.com/GMrr5fND

This one isn't (4.2.1)

https://pastebin.com/Pe9LNiCg

Exact same command line apart from ffmpeg path

Also x265 is working. (4.2.1) Weird.

https://pastebin.com/wUwKfv1u